# Какой плагин позволит редактору Atom автоматически закрывать теги как в Brackets?

Tags: atom

Какой плагин позволит редактору Atom автоматически закрывать теги как в Brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть популярный плагин: [Auto Close HTML](https://atom.io/packages/autoclose-html).

В обычных условиях строчные теги будут закрываться той же строке, а блочные - на новой, с последовательностью символов `\n\t\n` между открывающим и закрывающим тегом.

`\n` - это символ переноса строки
`\t` - символ табуляции

Подробное описание и настройки доступны по ссылке выше.

Comment: смотри, я например пишу тег <div> потом пишу </ нажимаю ентер и он закрывает тег </div>.Вот такое нужно для Atom.

Answer (score 0):

В атоме есть встроенный плагин. Сочетание клавиш - CTRL+ALT+.